# sqlite: Cannot select id while rowid works

Tags: ios, sql, iphone, sqlite

I have a database schema like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
    rephotos (id integer AUTO_INCREMENT, 
              beforePath text, 
              beforeThumbnail blob, 
              afterPath text, 
              afterThumbnail blob, 
              PRIMARY KEY(id)
              );
```

When trying to `SELECT` the ids in the database like this

```
SELECT id FROM rephotos;
```

it prints nothing. However if I use

```
SELECT rowid FROM rephotos;
```

it works as expected. The reason this confuses me is that the [sqlite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) specifically states that

> If a table contains a column of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then that
>   column becomes an alias for the ROWID. You can then access the ROWID
>   using any of four different names, the original three names described
>   above or the name given to the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column. All these
>   names are aliases for one another and work equally well in any
>   context.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) says:

> A PRIMARY KEY column only becomes an integer primary key if the declared type name is exactly "INTEGER". Other integer type names like "INT" or "BIGINT" or "SHORT INTEGER" or "UNSIGNED INTEGER" causes the primary key column to behave as an ordinary table column with integer affinity and a unique index, not as an alias for the rowid.

AUTOINCREMENT is spelled wrong, so the column type is not exactly "INTEGER" but "INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT".

Comment: I marked id as `PRIMARY KEY(id)`, does that not suffice?